# check on server side if youtube video exist

Tags: node.js, youtube-api

How to check if youtube video exists on node.js app server side:

```
var youtubeId = "adase268_";

// pseudo code
youtubeVideoExist = function (youtubeId){
   return true; // if youtube video exists
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [youtube-feeds](https://github.com/fvdm/nodejs-youtube#video-1) module. Works fast (~200ms) and no need `API_KEY`

```
youtube = require("youtube-feeds");

existsFunc = function(youtubeId, callback) {
  youtube.video(youtubeId, function(err, result) {
    var exists;
    exists = result.id === youtubeId;
    console.log("youtubeId");
    console.log(youtubeId);
    console.log("exists");
    console.log(exists);
    callback (exists);
  });
};


var notExistentYoutubeId = "y0srjasdkfjcKC4eY"
existsFunc (notExistentYoutubeId, console.log)

var existentYoutubeId = "y0srjcKC4eY"
existsFunc (existentYoutubeId, console.log)
```

output:

```
❯ node /pathToFileWithCodeAbove/FileWithCodeAbove.js
youtubeId
y0srjcKC4eY
exists
true
true
youtubeId
y0srjasdkfjcKC4eY
exists
false
false
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the youtube API per-se, you can look for the thumbnail image:

Valid video = 200 - OK:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/gC4j-V585Ug/0.jpg

Invalid video = 404 - Not found:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/gC4j-V58xxx/0.jpg

I thought I could make this work from the browser since you can load images from a third-party site without security problems.  But testing it, it's failing to report the 404 as an error, probably because the content body is still a valid image.  Since you're using node, you should be able to look at the HTTP response code directly.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of an approach that doesn't involve making a separate HTTP request to the video link to see if it exists or not unless you know beforehand of a set of video IDs that are inactive,dead, or wrong.

Here's an example of something that might work for you. I can't readily tell if you're using this as a standalone script or as part of a web server. The example below assumes the latter, assuming you call a web server on `/video?123videoId` and have it respond or do something depending on whether or not the video with that ID exists. It uses Node's [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library, which you can install with `npm install request`:

```
var request = require('request');

// Your route here. Example on what route may look like if called on /video?id=123videoId
app.get('/video', function(req, response, callback){
    var videoId = 'adase268_'; // Could change to something like request.params['id']
    request.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+videoId, function(error, response, body){
        if(response.statusCode === 404){
            // Video doesn't exist. Do what you need to do here.
        }
        else{
            // Video exists.
            // Can handle other HTTP response codes here if you like.
        }
    });
});

// You could refactor the above to take out the 'request.get()', wrap it in a function
// that takes a callback and re-use in multiple routes, depending on your problem.
```

Comment: You can use `HEAD` instead of `GET`

Comment: sorry, this method not working for me: allways status code 200 even if video not exists

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to  look for the thumbnail image. In NodeJS it would be something like

```
var http = require('http');

function isValidYoutubeID(youtubeID) {
  var options = {
    method: 'HEAD',
    host: 'img.youtube.com',
    path: '/vi/' + youtubeID + '/0.jpg'
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    if (res.statusCode == 200){
        console.log("Valid Youtube ID");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid Youtube ID");
    }
  });

  req.end();
}
```

API_KEY is not needed. It is quite fast because there is only header check for statusCode 200/404 and image is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

@rodrigomartell is on the right track, in that your check function will need to make an HTTP call; however, just checking the youtube.com URL won't work in most cases. You'll get back a 404 if the videoID is a malformed ID (i.e. less than 11 characters or using characters not valid in their scheme), but if it's a properly formed videoID that just happens to not correspond to a video, you'll still get back a 200. It would be better to use an API request, like this (note that it might be easier to use the request-json library instead of just the request library):

```
request = require('request-json');

var client = request.newClient('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/');

youtubeVideoExist = function (youtubeId){
 var apikey ='YOUR_API_KEY'; // register for a javascript API key at the Google Developer's Console ... https://console.developers.google.com/
 client.get('videos/?part=id&id='+youtubeId+'&key='+apikey, function(err, res, body) {
  if (body.items.length) {
   return true; // if youtube video exists
  }
  else {
   return false;
  }
 });
};
```

Comment: I got problems with getting `API_KEY`, I configured it, but anyway got response with message: `Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.`