# node.js how to check if a link is a valid youtube link

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube

So I have searched for an answer to see if a link is a valid youtube link. If it is a valid youtube link (The link links to an actual video) I run some code. There was a 2014 stack overflow question about the same thing ([check on server side if youtube video exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645500/check-on-server-side-if-youtube-video-exist)), but I tried all methods and it did not work. Any help?

Comment: `I tried all methods and it did not work.` - I just tried the first one (that does not need any external libraries) and it works just fine - which version of node.js are you running? my guess is you've messed up the code or expect it to be synchronous - show the code you tried and failed with

Comment: Hello @JaromandaX, I could not find an answer that did not use any external libraries. Could you please link to that page? Also, I am running node.js v.7.10.0.

Comment: Link to that page? But you already linked to it

Comment: The first (not accepted) answer does not require external libraries - and nodejs is all about external libraries if you want to do anything more than "hello world"

Comment: I see just one post not mentioning any external libraries, the one by Julian.  What is he talking about `Since you're using node, you should be able to look at the HTTP response code directly.`? How do you do that?

Comment: you are wrong, the first answer by `OdkoPP` has no external library - you need to know a little bit about node.js ... `require` does not always mean `external library` - `http` is not external

Comment: I am pretty sure I have tried that, and that is not the first one for mine, it is the last one. I will try it again.

Comment: I just tried that, and putting in a random valid youtube link ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6rOSe3EsdMasd) if you are interested, gives me an Invalid Youtube ID. It also gives me an error: `Error: Video id (U6rOSe3EsdMasd) does not match expected format (/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}$/)`

Comment: no, wait, that's not a valid youtube ID - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6rOSe3EsdMasd has too many characters in it!! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6rOSe3EsdM is the correct URL

Comment: hmmm... how does it work then?

Comment: Anyway, I changed it to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6rOSe3EsdM and it still gives me an invalid Youtube Id

Answer (score 0):

Since you use node.js you can use the request library to send a request and communicate with the response back with the library cheerio

I did a quick scrape and see that when a youtube link is unavailable these div elements appears:

```
  <div class="content">
    <h1 id="unavailable-message" class="message">
      The video you have requested is not available.
    </h1>
    <div id="unavailable-submessage" class="submessage">
      Sorry about that.
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can search for that div element with an id of "unavailable-submessage" and if it exists, the length is no longer 0 because it exists, and then continue with whatever code you want to continue with

```
request
.get(youryoutubelink, (err, response, body) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  const length = $("#unavailable-message").length;

  if (length > 0) { // if the video is unavailable
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something when the video exists
  }
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error with your code:
 .then(response => {
       ^

TypeError: request(...).then is not a function
I did npm install request and this is my code: (argresult is the Youtube link):

`const request = require('request');
request(argresult)
      .then(response => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
        if ( $("#unavailable-submessage").find("submessage").length !== 0 ) { // if the youtube link is unavailable this div element exists
          console.log('Unavailable');
        } else {
          console.log('Available');
        }
      });`

Comment: I am new, so I do not know how to put that in code blocks

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the code to a working and tested code. Try that one

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I do not have an error, but after using a valid youtube link, it console logs unavailable, when it clearly was a youtube link. Here is my code: `request.get(argresult, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        const length = $("#unavailable-message").length;

        if (length > 0) {
          console.log('Unavailable');
        } else {
          console.log('Available');
        }
      });`            I had this problem with the other ones I have tested